# Authenticate in Apache via System Account

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication

I currently have my apache server to authenticate via a password file created from htpasswd.  Configured as such:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secured Site"
AuthUserFile "/etc/apache2/users.passwd"
```

How can I change this to authenticate via local system accounts and additionaly restrict to only a subset of local system accounts in a specified group?

Answer (score 13):

As suggested by David Z, you can use mod-authnz-external. Use it with [pwauth](https://github.com/phokz/pwauth) for example.

If you are running Debian or a derivative:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-authnz-external pwauth
a2enmod authnz_external
```

In your configuration, add

```
<IfModule mod_authnz_external.c>
  DefineExternalAuth pwauth pipe /usr/sbin/pwauth
</IfModule>
```

And in the Directory section or your .htaccess file:

```
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Login"
    AuthBasicProvider external
    AuthExternal pwauth
    Require valid-user
    # or
    # Require user jules jim ...
```

Finally reload the configuration with `apache2ctl restart` or `service apache2 reload`.

See also [this documentation](https://github.com/phokz/mod-auth-external/wiki/Installation).

Comment: From [INSTALL](https://github.com/phokz/mod-auth-external/blob/master/mod_authnz_external/INSTALL), section "CONFIGURATION" -> "Configurating the External Authenticator" -> "For External Authentication Programs": `AddExternalAuth` and `SetExternalAuthMethod` are old-style syntax commands. The new-style syntax uses only one command: `DefineExternalAuth pwauth pipe /usr/sbin/pwauth`.

Comment: **For anyone using `pwauth`, make sure the `pwauth` binary has setuid permissions!** You can do so with this command: `chmod u+s /usr/bin/pwauth`. When Apache invokes `pwauth` and setuid permissions are not set, the status code of `1` (unknown) is always returned. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pwauth/+bug/579846

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to look into something like [`mod_auth_pam`](http://pam.sourceforge.net/mod_auth_pam/). PAM is the "Pluggable Authentication Module" system and the standard Linux (I'm assuming this is Linux) system login mechanism relies on PAM to do its authentication.

Another option is [`mod_authnz_external`](http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/), which will look directly at the `/etc/shadow` file to authenticate accounts.

*EDIT*: Apparently `mod_auth_pam` is no longer maintained (unfortunately), so maybe `mod_authnz_external` would be a better bet...

Answer (score 2):

The Apache module [`mod_auth_pam`](http://pam.sourceforge.net/mod_auth_pam/documentation.html) will do exactly this for you.
You enable the module, and the config file should look something like

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "secure area"
require group staff
require user webmaster
```

And you're all set.

Comment: Seems the module you linked to is designed for Apache 1.3 or 2.0. http://blog.thirsch.de/2007/02/21/how-to-get-mod_auth_pam-running-on-apache-22x/ gives hints on making it work.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the same issue. Here's my solution since `mod_auth_pam` is dead and no one has addressed the original question,

> "authenticate via local system accounts...**in a specified group**"

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, so flavor the package installation to your own system. For this example, I'm hosting a directory `/var/www/data` and only want users in the `data` group to have access. I'm assuming you have an Apache installation running and the `data` group already created.

As mentioned before, you'll need to grab `pwauth` and the `authnz` software. Additionally, you will need `mod-authz-unixgroup` for group authentication. You can install them using,

```
apt install libapache2-mod-authz-unixgroup libapache2-mod-authnz-external pwauth
```

Next, change the permissions of pwauth (this was fixed on 2020-06-02, but I'll leave this here for older releases) by using,

```
chmod u+s /usr/sbin/pwauth
```

Then, write up your apache2 VirtualHost configuration. Here's a very simple example,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Host Info
    ServerName cool.things
    ServerAdmin reallycooldude@cool.things
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    # Where the logs go
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # Setup external authentication
    <IfModule mod_authnz_external.c>
        AddExternalAuth pwauth /usr/sbin/pwauth
        SetExternalAuthMethod pwauth pipe
    </IfModule>

    # Load an _h5ai index
    <Directory "/var/www/data">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php /data/_h5ai/public/index.php

        # Setup Basic Authentication
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "data group members only"
        AuthBasicProvider external
        AuthExternal pwauth

        # Only allow members of the "data" group
        Require unix-group data

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally, you'll need to reload, restart, and check the status of Apache for errors.

```
service apache2 reload 
service apache2 restart 
service apache2 status
```